# Can't get automatic closing brackets in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm making an app with a basic code editor for myself.
When creating auto brackets I ran into a problem.
When my cursor is in line 4 of the textbox and I press '(' It moves the '(' to line 1 of the textbox and it adds a ')' in line 4.

This is my code:

```
private void editorTB_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        bool CSharpMode = true;

        if (CSharpMode == true)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '(')
            {
                editorTB.Text += ")";
            }
        }
    }
```

editorTB is my richtextbox1 control.

I hope someone can help me resolve the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show more code, where are you setting the value for editorTB?

Comment: I just created a textbox control and named it editorTB.

Comment: Changed the editorTB.Text to textbox1.Text so it's more understandable

Comment: And how are you detecting the input of '(' bracket? Are you looping through the string in textbox or detecting keystrokes?

Comment: The code basically says: If the user is in the textbox control and he presses the ( button then add a )

Comment: It will be easier to see that code as well. What I am understanding is that the code you posted in the question is working fine as the bracket ')' is being added in the correct position but the typed bracket '(' is moved to 1st line. You need to show  all code related to detection of first bracket for people to help you.

Comment: Do you have another listener for `key` related events on the same textbox? from what I can tell seems that there are actually two different pieces of code running at the same time...

Comment: This is the only code that is affecting the textbox at the moment...

Comment: I posted the entire code above. It shouldn't affect the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code inserts `")"` char after `"("` char in anywhere textbox.

case: TEXT(

Output: Text()

Case1: TE(XT

Output1: TE()XT

check this `keypress` event. the key is here e.Handled is true. otherwise it wont work.

```
       if (e.KeyChar == '(')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            const string insertText = ")";
            var selectionIndex = textBox1.SelectionStart;           
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(selectionIndex, "(");
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(selectionIndex +1, insertText);
            textBox1.SelectionStart = selectionIndex + insertText.Length;
        }
```

Comment: @Thow glad to help!